# The cost of memory allocation on the (tacitly assumed) Word RAM machine?

Tags: computation-models

Consider a particular algorithm that solves the binary search problem (or similar stuff) by performing $\sqrt{n}$ simple operations on numbers of
$\log(n)$ bits. Suppose this algorithm works on a `Word Ram` machine with
word size $w=\log(n)$. What happens if the algorithm uses a memory area
with $n$ numbers that are **not** initialized (like when using `malloc` in `C`)
because only a few of them are really touched/used?

Some sources (example [here](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~cs125/fall14/lec6.pdf)) say that the memory of a `Word Ram` machine is just there, and there is  no allocation, *i.e.*, we simply have $n=2^w$ memory cells available since the very beginning 
. Other sources give different formalizations, but still the memory
is just there. In this sense, the algorithm has complexity $O\left(\sqrt{n}\right)$.

Other sources (example [here](http://opendatastructures.org/versions/edition-0.1e/ods-cpp/1_3_Model_Computation.html)) consider the cost of performing memory allocations, so that
allocating $O(k)$ cells takes $O(k)$. In this sense, the algorithm has complexity $O(n)$ in the `Word RAM` model.

Even reference books (*e.g.,* the Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et al.) do
not provide a very formal description of the `Word RAM` machine. In my sense, they do not
seem to give *so* much attention (*i.e.,* there is about one page, Section 2.2) to
specify very clearly the machine on which all complexities of their algorithms
are calculated. So I could not find a response to my question. The `Word RAM` is not as clearly and as uniformly specified as the Turing machine.

Where can I find the "true" `Word RAM` machine ?

Comment: I don't know whether there *is* a single true Word RAM model.  It all comes down to how you define the model.  In the version that I am familiar with, the Word RAM model does not have a malloc operation.  It has only some basic operations (e.g., array reads and writes, arithmetic operations, conditional statements).  If you want to implement malloc, you need to implement it yourself and then analyze the running time of your particular implementation.  There may be other versions that do have a malloc and make some assumptions about its running time.